# How to split the bootstrap card in to two columns?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

In my angular 9 app i have a component that uses bootstrap cards. I'm trying to generate this layout on my component::

**On the desktop view layout should look like this::**

[image]

**On the mobile view layout should look like this ::**

[image]

The code i have written to generate the above did not generate the above layout as expected

here is my code ... this was extracted from a large dynamically generated set of bootstrap rows in my angular app and instead dynamically generating i have put the rows as hard coded so its easy for the reader to understand

```
<div class="animated fadeIn" 
    style="margin-left: 2%;margin-right: 2%;margin-top: 2%;width: 80%;" 
    id="qgroup-div-g1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">              
              <div class="row" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xl mb-3 mb-xl-0">      
                    <h5 style="text-align: left;">
                        Sample Header                  

                        <button type="button" 
                                class="btn btn-success mr-1" 
                                style="position:absolute;right: 10px;top:5px;"  
                                (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
                                [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed">
                                <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down"></i>
                        </button> 


                    </h5>
                </div>
              </div>    
            </div>

            <div [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed" id="qgroup-collapse-wrapper-g1">
                <div class="card-body">
                     <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="row justify-content-md-center" id="row1" style="display: flex;">                
                                <div class="col-8">                        
                                    TEXT1
                                </div> 
                                <div  id="d_1" class="col-xs-auto">                     

                                    <AngularComponent  id="comp1"  
                                                value='10' 
                                                max="5" 
                                                color="blue" 
                                                size="40px"                                      
                                                (progress)="onProgress($event,'comp1', 1, 1 )">
                                    </AngularComponent>

                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="row justify-content-md-center" id="row2" style="display: flex;">                
                                <div class="col-8">                        
                                    TEXT2
                                </div> 
                                <div  id="d_2" class="col-xs-auto">                     

                                    <AngularComponent  id="comp1"  
                                                value='10' 
                                                max="5" 
                                                color="blue" 
                                                size="40px"                                      
                                                (progress)="onProgress($event,'comp1', 1, 1 )">
                                    </AngularComponent>

                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.col-->
  </div>
</div>
```

How do i generate above expected laypout?

Comment: Have used `material-ui`? try this, this will take care of web responsiveness for devices. https://material.angular.io/

Comment: @Manjuboyz all components of my app is created using bootstrap i would like to make all streamlined with bootstrap so at the moment material UI is out of the question but please i would also like to know how it can be done in material UI as well.   but my first choice is not material UI its bootstrap. please provide your answer in material UI as well thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 450px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;} 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">

    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <hr>
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your solution is actually using cards. Also, I'm missing why there is a navbar in your solution.